# Prove that every prime factor of $12x^2+1$ has the form $6n+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer, prove that every prime factor of $12x^2+1$ has the form $6m+1$, where $m$ is an integer.

I've gone as far as knowing that all primes $p>3$ are either $6m+1$ or $6m-1$, how do I use this, not sure whether to even use that.

I know about the Legendre symbol and quadratic reciprocity

Comment: What have you learned about quadratic residues?  Please edit this into your question rather than add a comment.

Comment: Do not delete questions that received an answer.

Answer (score 2):

2 and 3 can be easily excluded, so let $p$ be a prime which is at least 5.

Then $p$ is either congruent to 1 or 5 modulo 6. Suppose $p \ | \ 12n^2 + 1$ and $p \equiv 5 \pmod 6$. Then we have $12n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ and hence

$$
\Big(\frac{-3}{p}\Big) = 1,
$$

where $()$ is the Legendre symbol. By the rules of Legendre symbol and the quadratic reciprocity, we have

$$
\Big(\frac{-3}{p}\Big) = \Big(\frac{-1}{p}\Big)\Big(\frac{3}{p}\Big) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (-1)^{\frac{2\times(p-1)}{4}} \Big(\frac{p}{3}\Big) = \Big(\frac{p}{3}\Big) = -1,
$$

which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I think i just need to look at this over but where does the $-3$ come from?

Comment: Because $12n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ means $(6n)^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$.

Comment: How did you come to $(-3｜p)=1$, what if you let $p≡1(mod)6$, how does  $(-3｜p)$ change?

Comment: Please see the computations above. That is a result by multiplicative law of (), formula for $(\frac{-1}p)$, and the reciprocity law. If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ then $(\frac{-3}p) = (\frac p3) = 1$.

Comment: From the first line of my comment, $(6n)^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$, so $-3$ is a quadratic residue and hence $(\frac{-3}{p})$ has to be 1 by the definition of Legendre symbol.

Comment: This makes perfect sense thankyou sir